# Publishing C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application, setup-deployment

I have developed a C# console application using VS2010. Now i would like to make it into a setup.exe. Is it possible to have this setup.exe as a standalone file to run my program? Meaning how can i achieve in obtaining setup.exe that when i click on that file it will run my console without even opening VS and without the need of my project folder on the workstation.
I have tried numerous time doing myself but failed up till now.
Some advice please.

Thanks, 
10e5x

Comment: use Visual studio installer or some third party installer as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers

Comment: When you build your solution, the `Bin\Debug` or `Bin\Release` folder (in your solution folder) should contain an exe that is your console application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can publish it. Go to your solution explorer. Right click on it. publish the application. After finishing the publishing wizard, you can get the set up file in publish folder. 
or 
you can simply copy the exe file directly from the Bin folder and paste it wherever you want.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: i published my app, but i can't find its install location. i tried to track from "Uninstall or change a program" but i couldn't find the location. Can you tell me what can be the default location of published application after installation ?

Comment: Publishing isn't installing. It is simply moving a project output to a specified location. You need to create an installer project and reference your console app and any dependencies. The installer registers the application with Windows in addition to adding it to a designated installation directory.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the Steps

1) Firslty build the code
2) Then go to your projects folder
3) Open Debug/Bin
4) Inside Bin you can see the exe file. That file you can copy on any work station and run your console application.

Please do remember be confirm in which .NET version ur program is compiled. If suppose you compiled your program in .NET version 3.5 and running your program in .NET version 2 . It will not work

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help:) This way also work. however i am using freelancer way.

Comment: That assumes the console app doesn't have any dependencies at all. Won't work if it references DLLs that aren't installed in the GAC or other files.

Comment: To mention that the .exe file will be slightly, very slightly slower (if applicable to you). It is always to go ahead with the release. The debug version will check debugger attachment and a lot of other stuffs.

Comment: Funny, the published versions do not work, but the release versions do! (weird IO error - and I  did notice config files are not included in the published version)